# Как вставить содержимое в iframe без url или файлов

Tags: html, iframe

У меня есть одна проблема: Мне нужно вывести на айфрейм содержимое без url файла и тому подобное

```
<iframe src='<b>Привет мир!</b>' />
```

но у меня получаеться пустой фрейм и я никак не могу найти в интернете решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно разместить скрипт создания элементов и стилей непосредственно в атрибуте `src`:

```html
<iframe src="javascript:
             let el = document.createElement(`B`);
             el.textContent=`Привет мир!`;
             document.body.append(el);">
</iframe>

<iframe src="javascript:
             document.head.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, `<style>.bold{font-weight:700}</style>`);
             document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`,`<div class='bold'>Привет мир!</div>`);">
</iframe>
```

Ну и не забывайте, что `<iframe>` - парный тег. То есть закрывать его *обязательно*.

Comment: Выручил спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Для этого у `<iframe>` существует метод [`.srcdoc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/srcdoc):

```js
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe')

iframe.widht = 300
iframe.height = 200
iframe.srcdoc = `<b>Hello World</b>`

document.body.append(iframe)
```

Comment: тоже отлично хороший спомсб

Comment: В своё время, в каком-то проекте, сильно намаялся с frame/iframe, по прихоти заказчика. Получил кучу инфы по этой теме, но этот атрибут вижу в первый раз. Спасибо.